# JVM lifecycle description

Tags: java, jvm

I recently developed a need to understand what's happening in JVM and I was looking for some documents or tutorials that would explain things like:

- What threads are being created on start and why?
- How GC is generally handling the memory, what is GC responsible for and how does it fit into JVM standards?
- How does JVM handle different types of invoke* opcodes? How does it perform method lookup?
- How is method area organised, what is exactly stored there? How do method stacks work with method areas?
- How does JVM handle threads, prepare and execute?

I know that it will differ for different implementations, but I will take whatever materials you will give me. Something more closer to code than general overview of architecture. There are people that know cool sh*t and I don't know where to find it. I know that this question might sound naive :)

Comment: That's a lot of questions - there are some details about a virtual machine here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html. GC is another question

Answer (score 0):

```
1) JVM boots up and setups up the various memory areas that the GC
will be managing, it will also setup some system threads
2)Look the jar file manifest to determine the class that has the main method to load
3)Load the main class and verify that the byte code in the just loaded class is correct and not doing anything illegal.
4)resolve what classes are needed by the class being loaded and load those classes each class being loaded goes through step 3 and 4
5)Find the the byte code for the main method and execute it.

This is just a brief description

You can find everydetail in the book Inside the Java Virtual Machine
2nd Edition
```

Answer (score 0):

> What threads are being created on start and why?

I suggest you take a thread dump of a simple program and google each of the thread names.  Most of them you don't need to know anything about.

> How GC is generally handling the memory, what is GC responsible for and how does it fit into JVM standards?

The GC is responsible for cleaning up memory which is no longer referenced to free up space. It should do it in an efficient manner.

> How does JVM handle different types of invoke* opcodes? How does it perform method lookup?

If you ever need to understand what these do exactly I suggest you read about them in the spec.  Until then I would assume that if you think you need to know what these do, you are doing something wrong.

> How is method area organised, what is exactly stored there?

You have the Heap, Stacks, Perm Gen/Metaspace, direct memory, memory mapped files and shared libraries.

The main one to worry about is the Heap where objects are stored and possibly the Perm Gen for code for Java <= 7.

> How do method stacks work with method areas?

The stack grows each time you make an actual call. If the call is inlined, it might grow less, or not at all.

> How does JVM handle threads, prepare and execute?

It doesn't. The OS and the CPU does all the real work.

> I recently developed a need to understand what's happening in JVM

There is a lot you could learn, but unless you have a use for it which is likely to be about 1%, you will forget it.  I suggest you focus on more specific problems and information which are directly useful. e.g. there are over 500 Java options, but very few know what they all do. You might only need to know 5 without looking them up.